# как работает функция

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.x, ctypes

https://github.com/artur1214/winstr/blob/master/winstr.py

Этот скрипт был создан для python 2.7 мне интересна функция `Win32CryptUnprotectData` ([319 строка](https://github.com/artur1214/winstr/blob/master/winstr.py#L319)) во-первых: что она делает, 2 - как переписать ее для python 3.6 (просто вызов ее из под 3 питона вызывает ошибку):

```
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled17/steal.py", line 62, in 
<module>
password = Win32CryptUnprotectData(log[2])
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled17\winstr.py", line 321, in 
Win32CryptUnprotectData
bufferIn    = c_buffer(str(cipherText), len(cipherText))
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 70, in c_buffer
return create_string_buffer(init, size)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 63, in create_string_buffer
raise TypeError(init)
TypeError: 
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\xd0\x8c\x9d\xdf\x01\x15\xd1\x11\x8cz\x00\xc0O\xc2\x97\xeb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xac\xbc\x1cU\x9a_FM\x89To&n!\xf1\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10f\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00 
\x00\x00\x00\xaf^\r\xdc\xddH3.\xd8\xe3\x84\xd0\xb3\xc2a\n}\x97xy\x08\x88\x9c`\x8bK\xf6\x19\xe1\x960}\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x80\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x7f\xbd\x172\xe4X\xa0f\xfa\x92c\x88\xc3\xad\x9bK\xd0\xb5\x95\xc5\xa0\x08_L\xa8)\xae\x01\x0c\xf2T6\x10\x00\x00\x00\xb7\xcc\xe5e\x9c\x99\xa9-\xed\xf0\x18\xc3Q7\xe2\xc9@\x00\x00\x00I\x10}\xe1?\xdaK\x0c\xf4m\x96F\xd9C\x19\xf0,\xb5C\xac\xea\xb6\xe6\xfb$W\xb6\xc4\xd6\x06\xec\xb9\x93\xbb\xac\xcd\xde\x8c\xc7\x04\xbcn+"\xabZalL\x85Qa\x94\x19\x08\xce\xb1\xd2\x14\xd0\x0f\x12\xe1\xf4'
```

смысл примерно в следующем: хром хранит сохраненные пароли в `C:\Users\<имя пользователя>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\` в файле `Login data`  (файл можно открыть как файл sqlite3) там есть поле password_value вот пример того что там лежит:

`1,0,0,0,208,140,157,223,1,21,209,17,140,122,0,192,79,194,151,235,1,0,0,0,228,39,241,74,52,90,102,73,173,176,72,56,224,107,190,75,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,16,102,0,0,0,1,0,0,32,0,0,0,123,88,84,174,228,192,114,255,29,130,249,202,88,242,202,10,159,192,90,167,150,17,180,170,202,184,178,82,156,137,19,118,0,0,0,0,14,128,0,0,0,2,0,0,32,0,0,0,51,125,211,125,67,196,108,8,239,205,32,206,146,255,59,126,149,197,61,122,166,160,243,94,99,24,21,122,235,133,83,169,16,0,0,0,168,39,59,49,253,59,15,72,85,69,124,251,83,59,179,196,64,0,0,0,174,66,19,237,148,130,131,75,255,217,242,14,91,154,155,12,219,63,240,195,199,40,193,201,61,13,199,44,38,99,220,229,104,215,11,63,78,187,224,246,91,179,41,76,125,179,227,44,129,71,199,192,83,134,68,209,225,90,33,146,77,38,83,81`

во 2 питоне при передаче этого в  `Win32CryptUnprotectData` возвращался расшифрованный пароль на сколько я знаю данная функция на основе уникального пароля для каждого пользователя, то есть если я получу то что лежит в чужом пк в password_value то у себя я это уже на расшифрую, как переписать эту функцию для python3?

P.S если у вас то что я привел выше не расшифруется помните, что у вас нет моего уникального пароля, попробуйте со своим файлом и своим хромом

P.P.S если я плохо объяснил: я получаю строку типа выше указанной, и получаю ее в виде нормальной строки, как сделать чтоб это работало под 3 питоном?

Comment: код писал не я, если что извините если он выглядит странно

Comment: Добавили бы функцию сюда. И кст, в гитхабе можно ссылку скидывать вплоть до строчки файлика

Comment: Да, но проблема в том что функция эта использует многие переменные файла, и я не уверен, что если их выдернуть, я не потеряю другие нужные вещи